# SQL get the row after and before a specific ID

Tags: mysql

I have a query like :

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `press`"
                    ." WHERE "SOME CONDITONS 
                    ." GROUP BY `pressID`"
                    ." ORDER BY `date` DESC"
                    .";";
```

This query return an array of press, order by `date`.

I need to modify this query to get ONLY ONE press before and after (two queries, one for each) a specific ID, the id field is `pressID`.

Any ideas ?

I can do that with a specific treatment after my query but I think it's better if i do that directly in my query.

Thanks !

Edit :

My query return an ordered array of datas like :

```
array(XXX) {
  [0]=>
  array(XXX) {
    ["pressID"]=>     string(4) "1811"
  },
  [1]=>
  array(XXX) {
    ["pressID"]=>     string(3) "450"
  }
  ,
  [2]=>
  array(XXX) {
    ["pressID"]=>     string(1) "3"
  }
  ......
}
```

I need to modify this query (or create a new one) to get only the element before a specific id, and in a second query, the element after a specific id.

If i have id=450, i need to get for the before query press with id=1811, and for the after query press with id=3.

Comment: Why dont you use **BETWEEN**? `WHERE id BETWEEN x AND y`

Comment: Because the order is not the id, but the date

Comment: you can't order by `date` if you didn't group by `date`. right now your query will return one `date` per `pressid`. and could you give us an idea what is **SOME CONDITION** could be like?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want your query to return only 3 rows? Or do you want additional queries? Also define "before" and "after"... before and after what? Can you give an exemple of the results you are expecting?

Comment: Check my edit, do you understand now ?

Comment: It's a bit clearer yes. Any particular reason you want to do this in mysql instead of PHP? It looks to me like SQL is not the best tool for that.

Comment: Also could you answer to @Alex comment? What is the logic for ordering and grouping on a different field? How do you know what `date` will end up being?

Comment: it is absolutely not clear :-). if you have records: `(1,'2015-01-01'),(2,'2015-01-01'),(2,'2015-01-02'),(1,'2015-01-02')` for example and your `WHERE` clause should return 3rd record somehow `(2,'2015-01-02')` where **pressID=2** and **date=2015-01-02** where do you expect to see **pressID=1** *BEFORE* or *AFTER* ??

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the rows before and after, but not the middle row, maybe something like this? Get the lowest id greater and the greatest id less than the specific id:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `press`"
                ." WHERE pressID = (SELECT MIN(pressID) FROM `press` WHERE pressID > specificID)"
                ." OR pressID = (SELECT MAX(pressID) FROM `press` WHERE pressID < specificID)"
                ." GROUP BY `date`"
                ." ORDER BY `date` DESC"
                .";";
```

edit: since you are ordering by date:

```
SELECT * FROM press
WHERE date = (
    SELECT MIN(date) FROM press
    WHERE
        date > (SELECT date FROM press WHERE pressID = specific_id)
)
OR date = (
    SELECT MAX(date) FROM press
    WHERE
        date < (SELECT date FROM press WHERE pressID = specific_id)
)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: And if all ids are not in the good order ? Maybe i can have id 5 < 80 < 1

Answer (score 1):

As the others specify in the comments, you need to clarify some aspect of your model. Are your pressID unique ? Is there only one pressID per date ? Now if the answer is yes for both questions why not using `limit` ?

First you retrieve the date of your "*specific ID*" :

```
SELECT date FROM press WHERE pressID = specific_id;
```

Then you can easily create your two queries :

*For the one before:*

```
SELECT * FROM press 
WHERE date <= specific_id_date** and pressID <> specific_id 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

*For the one after:*

```
SELECT * FROM press 
WHERE date >= specific_id_date and pressID <> specific_id 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```